# Получение getResourceAsStream html-файла

Tags: java, кодировка

Есть html код как ресурс, который я хочу получить в виде строки, и далее вставить его в тело письма и отправить. Но при этом заменив данные. Обычная ситуация - регистрация нового юзера.

Для тестирования написал следующий код:

```
public void test()
{
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/emailtemplates/new-employee.html")));
        String s = reader.readLine();
        while (s != null)
        {
            System.out.println(s);
            s = reader.readLine();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Html он находит, читает его строками, но! При выводе в консоль получаю абракадабру.

```
<p>
    Ð”Ð¾Ð±Ñ€Ð¾Ð³Ð¾ Ð´Ð½Ñ?!
</p>
```

Пробовал указывать кодировку InputStreamReader UTF-8, тогда вместо абракадабры вопросы. Где мной была допущена ошибка?

Comment: Читать надо в той кодировке, в которой у вас сохранен файл. А он у вас, судя по приведенному фрагменту, в CP1252 или CP1251. Проверить кодировку [можно тут](https://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/).

Comment: лучше всего файл пересохранить в utf-8

Comment: @enzo Благодарю, проверил кодировку. Спасибо за ссылку на прекрасный сервис.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо при чтении файла указывать кодировку

Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");